# i need to change each table cell onclick according to the combobox value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x ;
}
```

I want to be able to use that in each table td

this is my example 
i need to change the value in the table cell according the selected value in the combobox but it is alwayse only change the first cell not each cell onclick

please i need a help that when i click at any cell it changes into the combobox value 
please i need help

this is my example

https://jsfiddle.net/h5mdj1w7/1/

Comment: [ID's Must Be Unique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme), specifically because it will cause problems in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) and CSS when you try to interact with those elements.

Comment: i know that bro and i tried to change the js function from getelemetbyid into getelementsbyclassname but did not work

Comment: i need to click any cell and it changes into the combobox selected value ... can you help me please in that

Answer (score 2):

Use the `jQuery` event onclick to achieve this.

```
$("td").on("click", function(){
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  $(this).html(x);
})
```

```js
$("td").on("click", function(){
 var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  $(this).html(x);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>A demonstration of how to access a SELECT element</h3>

<select id="mySelect" >
  <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Pear</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
    <option>Apple</option>
  <option>Pear</option>
  <option>Banana</option>
  <option>Orange</option>
</select>

<table style="width:700px;height:700px;margin:0 auto;border:1px solid black;" >
<tr>
    <td style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;" > <div>Try it</div></td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;" > <div>Try it</div></td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;" > <div>Try it</div></td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;" > <div>Try it</div></td>
 <td style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;" > <div>Try it</div></td>
 <td style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;" > <div>Try it</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;" > <div>Try it</div></td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;" > <div>Try it</div></td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;" > <div>Try it</div></td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;" > <div>Try it</div></td>
 <td style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;" > <div>Try it</div></td>
 <td style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;" > <div>Try it</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;" > <div>Try it</div></td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;" > <div>Try it</div></td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;" > <div>Try it</div></td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;" > <div>Try it</div></td>
 <td style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;" > <div>Try it</div></td>
 <td style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;" > <div>Try it</div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;" > <div>Try it</div></td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;" > <div>Try it</div></td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;" > <div>Try it</div></td>
    <td style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;" > <div>Try it</div></td>
 <td style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;" > <div>Try it</div></td>
 <td style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;" > <div>Try it</div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: oh my god thank you so much really i appreciat it thank you so much